# Context Component Scan not finding my custom annotated beans

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, annotations

Hello I am trying to write a custom annotation for a Spring MVC webapp.But somehow annotated classes are not getting detected by Spring applicationContext.Here is my relevent code.

**Annotated class:**

```
@Component
@MigrationRequired(migrateFrom="Tiff",migrateTo="PDF-A")
public class WordTemplate extends Template{

}
```

**CustomAnnotationDefinition:**

```
@Target({ ElementType.TYPE })
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Documented
public @interface MigrationRequired {

    String migrateFrom() default "Tiff";
    String migrateTo() default "PDF-A";
}
```

**Class for detecting Annotation on ContextLoading**

```
public class MigrationHandler implements ApplicationContextAware, InitializingBean {

    private ApplicationContext applicationContext;

    @Override
    public void afterPropertiesSet() throws Exception {

        final Map<String, Object> myMaps = applicationContext.getBeansWithAnnotation(MigrationRequired.class);
        System.out.println("inside after properties set" + myMaps );//**Always giving an empty set**
        for (final Object myMap : myMaps.values()) {
            final Class<? extends Object> myClass = myMap .getClass();
            final MigrationRequired annotation = myClass .getAnnotation(MigrationRequired.class);
            System.out.println("Found myClass: " + myClass + ", with tags: " + annotation.migrateFrom());
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void setApplicationContext(final ApplicationContext applicationContext)
            throws BeansException {
        System.out.println("This is called");
        this.applicationContext = applicationContext;
    }
}
```

`applicationContext.xml` **relevant configuration**

```
<bean id="migrationHandler" class="com.test.annotation.MigrationHandler"/>

<context:component-scan base-package="com.test" >
<context:include-filter type="annotation"expression="com.test.annotation.MigrationRequired"/>
</context:component-scan>
<!--Other beans definition-->
```

So in method of `MigrationHandler` `afterPropertiesSet()` I am always getting `myMaps` as empty. Am I doing something wrong? 
Thank you.

Comment: not sure but I think you need to add `@Component` annotation to your annotation `MigrationRequired`, try adding and check.

Comment: try adding `String name();` to your annotation together with `@Component` like @Nandkumar mentioned. No additional work is required.

Comment: @White thanks adding name field it worked for me.Thanks alot

Answer (score -1):

Is MigrationHandler is a spring bean? if yes why don’t you autowire MigrationRequired.